# php - htaccess: redirect .png to .php page and display html

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, png

I have a folder in the root called `picture` and I want to redirect (applying only to this folder) all the `.png` urls to:

```
/picture/index.php
```

displaying the index.php html content. I mean redirect urls like:

`/picture.png`, `/picture/whatever.png`, etc

Actually this is my .htaccess file inside the picture folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/picture/(\w+)\.png$ /picture/index.php [L]
```

but if I go to `domain.com/picture.png` it returns 404

Comment: I am not very familiar with htaccess and php, I hope it is simple :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in **`/picture/.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /picture/

RewriteRule \.png$ index.php [L,NC]
```